# How do I mount an SD Card as /home/wb9688 by startup?

Tags: mount, fstab, ext4

I want to mount my SD Card as /home/wb9688 by startup using /etc/fstab.
My SD Card is formatted as ext4 and the UUID is `93afcc06-65be-4154-9b20-6593f14f6c93`.

A normal user must have read and write permissions.

How do I do that?

Answer (score 1):

First create your directory

```
sudo mkdir /home/wb9688
```

Note you need sudo since the dir is in /home, if you misstype and you mean to create it inside your home then you dont need sudo and command becomes

```
mkdir ~/wb9688
```

Now add the entry to fstab

```
sudo gedit /etc/fstab
```

then add the following

```
UUID=93afcc06-65be-4154-9b20-6593f14f6c93 /home/wb9688  ext4    defaults    0   0
```

Comment: /home/wb9688 already exists, because my username is wb9688

Comment: Then you shouldn't use it as mounting point, create a dir inside it to use it as mounting point

Comment: Can I mount it as /home?

Comment: It's not a good Idea you should mount on non-used directory, when you mount to /home then you'll not see the content of old /home. for that it's better to mount it in a folder inside your home /home/wb9688/new-dir

Comment: And when I copy all content of /home to my SD Card?

Comment: you can do it then

Comment: Can I then write to my home folder with a normal user (wb9688)?

Comment: You can mount the SD to a folder inside your home so if you want you can copy from and to easily

Comment: any way to mount the sd card reader without locking it to a particular SD card with a particular GUID?